# How to solve $(-3)^{1/3}$?

Tags: complex-numbers

(z is a complex number )How to solve $(1-z)^3=-3$? at first I try to calculate $(-3)^{1/3}=?$ according the answer $(3)^(1/3)*e^(i*((pi) +2(pi)*k))$ but why? the radius is (3)^(1/3) the angle isn't zero? the answer says$ 1. 1-(3*e^i)^{1/3} 2. 1+(3)^{1/3} 3. 1-(3*e^{-i})^{1/3}$

Comment: "calculate" meaning "solve"?

Comment: How have you defined "negative number to the power of 1 over odd number", i.e. $(-a)^{1/b}$ where $a>0$ and $b$ is odd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know that $z=(-3)^{\frac{1}{3}}$ is such a number, that:

$$z^3=-3$$

You can write down $z$ in [Polar form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Polar_form):

$$z=r(\cos \phi + i\sin \phi)$$

for some $r$ and $\phi$.By [De Moivre's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula):

$$z^3=r^3(\cos 3\phi+i\sin 3\phi)$$

But:

$$-3=(\sqrt[3]{3})^3(-1)$$

So $r=\sqrt[3]{3}$ and you should find all $\phi \in [0,2\pi)$, that:

$$\sin 3\phi=0$$

$$\cos 3 \phi=-1$$

Answer (score 2):

Using complex numbers in polar form, with a $2k\pi$ indeterminacy on the phase, you can write
$$(1-z)^3=3e^{(2k+1)i\pi}.$$
Then
$$1-z=\sqrt[3]3e^{(2k+1)i\pi/3}.$$
Given the periodicity of the imaginary exponential, only the cases $k=0,1,2$ give different solutions.

---

$$e^{\frac{i\pi}3}=\cos\frac{\pi}3+i\sin\frac{\pi}3=\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2i$$
$$e^{\frac{3i\pi}3}=\cos\frac{3\pi}3+i\sin\frac{3\pi}3=-1$$
$$e^{\frac{5i\pi}3}=\cos\frac{5\pi}3+i\sin\frac{5\pi}3=\frac12-\frac{\sqrt3}2i$$

Comment: why (2k+1)? isn't the angle zero, so 2*(pi)*k? where 1 came from?

Comment: No, the minus sign corresponds to $1\pi$.

Comment: isn't the angle should be $arctan(0/((-3)^(1/3)) $ and add 2*pi*k ?

Comment: isn't the final answer wrong? after number one suppose to be where minus plus?

Comment: No, $e^{2ki\pi}=+1$ and $e^{(2k+1)i\pi}=-1$. The $\arctan$ gives the argument with $k\pi$ indeterminacy, not $2k\pi$, so you can loose the sign.